# Oracle Apex Validation - Valid Product Name

Tags: oracle, validation, oracle-apex

I have a Validation beginner's question here:

I have a select list item, options:
Product
SKU

If the user selects the SKU option a new textfield Item is shown for the customer to write down the SKU number.
My validation then tries to prevent an invalid SKU to be inserted.
This is what I have so far:

```
declare 

  v_rows_approved_min number;
  v_rows_approved_max number;
  err varchar2(300);

begin

if :P8_PRODUCT_OR_SKU = 'SKU' -- THIS IS MY SELECT LIST ITEM
then

  err := 'Not a valid SKU';

  v_rows_approved_min := 1;
  select count(*) into v_rows_approved_max from SKU_TABLE;

  for cur_a in (select SKU from SKU_TABLE) 
  loop
    exit when v_rows_approved_min > v_rows_approved_max;
    if :P8_SKU = cur_a.SKU
    then return err;
    else null;
    end if;
    v_rows_approved_min := v_rows_approved_min + 1;

  end loop;

 else null;

 end if;

 end;
```

Not sure what's going on here, can anyone help please?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this validation is declared as plsql blck in  validation for field or somewhere else?
Plsql validations need return either true or false.
You are returning nothing.
Compare your P8_PRODUCT_OR_SKU against any logic that is acceptable by you then return true if accepted else false.

Comment: "My validation then tries to prevent an invalid SKU to be inserted. " >> how do you know that SKU is invalid? Your code looks ... well, maybe to complicated. How to simplify it? No idea, until you show us some sample data and explain *why* is something valid (or invalid).

Comment: what is your question ? Are you getting an error message ? Does it work and do you want it to be validated ? Does it not work and don't you know why ?

Answer (score 1):

This code is overly complex. It checks if a page item value exists in a table and returns an error if a match is found. This is done with a loop with some additional logic to exit the loop with the number of iterations reaches the select count. That last logic is not needed. If a table contains 5 rows, then the loop will have 5 iterations. No need to do a `SELECT count` from the table (v_rows_approved_max) and then check every iteration if that number has not been reached yet...

Also, there is no `RETURN` statement if not match is found, so that is added at the end.

Here is an attempt at a rewrite:

```
DECLARE
---- not needed
--  v_rows_approved_min NUMBER;
--  v_rows_approved_max NUMBER;
  err VARCHAR2(300) := 'Not a valid SKU';
BEGIN
  IF :P8_PRODUCT_OR_SKU = 'SKU' -- THIS IS MY SELECT LIST ITEM
  THEN
    ---- err can be defaulted in declaration
    --err := 'Not a valid SKU';
    
    --v_rows_approved_min := 1;
    
    ---- not needed see  below
    --SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_rows_approved_max FROM sku_table;

    FOR cur_a IN ( SELECT sku FROM sku_table ) LOOP
      ---- not needed. You're looping through the table, v_rows_approved_min will be > than v_rows_approved_max    
      --EXIT WHEN v_rows_approved_min > v_rows_approved_max;
      IF :P8_SKU = cur_a.sku THEN
        RETURN err;
---- not needed
--      ELSE
--        NULL;
      END IF;
---- not needed      
--      v_rows_approved_min := v_rows_approved_min + 1;
    END LOOP;

---- not needed
--  ELSE
--    NULL;
  END IF;
  -- you need to return something whenever the function ends...
  RETURN NULL;
END;
/
```

however...
This can be greatly simplified.

Create a validation of type "Rows returned"

Source:

```
SELECT
  1
  FROM
  sku_table WHERE sku = :P8_SKU
```

Error Message: Not a valid SKU

Server Side condition (Type Item = Value): Item: P8_PRODUCT_OR_SKU; Value: SKU

This does exactly the same thing.